# React Native Base API Service with Service Status

Tags: react-native, axios, service, tsx

I need a base API service for React Native. However, I want to dynamically track the status of the service. When I render the service status, it renders as "loaded", but when I check it inside the button click, it stays idle.

Is there a basic API request architecture and what is the problem with my service?

ApiService.tsx

```
const ApiService = <T>(
  endpoint: string,
  method: AxiosRequestConfig['method'],
  data?: any,
  headers?: AxiosRequestConfig['headers'],
) => {
  const [service, setService] = useState<_ApiResponse<T>>({
    serviceStatus: ServiceStatus.Idle,
  });
  const {isLoggedIn, accessToken, logout} = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(`WARNING: ${endpoint} Request Created`);
  const getData = async (data?: any): Promise<_ApiResponse<T>> => {
    try {
      console.log(`WARNING: ${endpoint} Request Sending..`);
      setService({serviceStatus: ServiceStatus.Loading});

      const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        url: `${endpoint}`,
        method,
        data,
        headers: {
          ...(isLoggedIn && accessToken
            ? {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
            : {}),
          ...headers,
        },
      };

      const res: AxiosResponse<_ApiResponse<T>> = await axios(config);
      const value: _ApiResponse<T> = {
        ...res.data,
        serviceStatus: ServiceStatus.Loaded,
      };

      setService({serviceStatus: ServiceStatus.Loaded});
      return value;
    } catch (error) {
      if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
        const statusCode = error.response?.status;
        switch (statusCode) {
          case 400:
            console.log('Bad request');
            break;
          case 401:
            console.log('Unauthorized');
            {
              isLoggedIn && accessToken;
              await refreshAccessToken();
            }
            break;
          case 403:
            console.log('Forbidden');
            break;
          case 404:
            console.log('Not found');
            break;
          default:
            console.log('An error occurred');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('An unexpected error occurred');
      }
      setService({serviceStatus: ServiceStatus.Failed});
      return {serviceStatus: 'failed'};
    }
  };


  return {service, request: getData};
};
export default ApiService;
```

Usage Page:

```
 const {service: reqisterService, request: reqisterRequest} =
    ApiService<Register>(Endpoint.Register, RequestMethod.Post);


const handleRegister = async (email: any, password: any) => {
        try {
      const body: Register = {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        passwordAgain: password,
      };

      const response = await reqisterRequest(body);
     

      if (reqisterService.serviceStatus == ServiceStatus.Loaded && reponse.status ) {
        showAlert({
          type: Alert.Default,
          title: 'E-postanızı kontrol edin ve hesabınızı onaylayın',
        });
        setVisibleRegisterModal(true);
        setRegisterButtonState(ButtonStatus.Disabled);
      }

      if (
        reqisterService.serviceStatus == ServiceStatus.Loaded &&
        response.status == false &&
        response.errors
      ) {
        showAlert({
          type: Alert.Danger,
          title: response.errors[0],
        });
        setRegisterButtonState(ButtonStatus.Idle);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Failed to send log ${e}`);
    }
  };
```

Basically, I want to track the instant status of the service and do all api submissions from here.